# Colors must be aRGB hex values?

Tags: python, pandas, data-cleaning, argb

So I was previously running some code for a pollution dataset, and the code was running just fine. Now, I get this error:
Colors must be aRGB hex values

The only line of code I have is the following:

```
pollution_jawn = pd.read_excel('ObservationData_irkfioc copy.xlsx')
```

I have no idea what the issue is, and I even tried deleting this file from my jupyterhub directory and uploading it, but even that did not work.

Answer (score 3):

Had similar issue, but found simple solution, just to reassign method **set** in RGB class in openpyxl/styles/colors.py, catching error with 'Colors must be aRGB hex values' and setting another color like white:

```
from openpyxl.styles.colors import WHITE, RGB
__old_rgb_set__ = RGB.__set__

def __rgb_set_fixed__(self, instance, value):
    try:
        __old_rgb_set__(self, instance, value)
    except ValueError as e:
        if e.args[0] == 'Colors must be aRGB hex values':
            __old_rgb_set__(self, instance, WHITE)  # Change color here

 RGB.__set__ = __rgb_set_fixed__
```

Hope it will help somebody

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by the other answer, a workaround this is to specify `engine='xlrd'` in `pd.read_excel`. However, for this to work, xlrd must be in version 1.2.0 (or lower).

To download the specific version (using anaconda), type in your terminal `conda install -c anaconda xlrd=1.2.0`.

After that is done, this should work (mind that you will get a `FutureWarning`, as this version of xlrd is deprecated:

```
pollution_jawn = pd.read_excel('ObservationData_irkfioc copy.xlsx', engine='xlrd')
```

Answer (score 1):

Had a similar issue after I updated to pandas 1.2.3. What worked for me is to specify

```
pd.read_excel(path_to_xlsx, engine='xlrd')
```

I suspect that the xlsx file I loaded used an older xls standard somewhere, since the option "`xlrd` supports old-style Excel files (.xls)" (from the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html))

Answer (score 1):

The .xlsx file was probably saved in an older version of Excel. What worked for me was to simply open the .xlsx file in a new version of Excel and then save it again. After that the error didn't turn up again.

Answer (score 1):

Not a python solution, but I opened the file with excel and removed all colors (font and background). The resulting file could be opened without trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Korney Burau answer works but resets all your default RGB to white which is not what you want, instead you can try

```
original_rgb_set = RGB.__set__

def custom_rgb_set(self, instance, value):
    if value == "0":
        pass
    else:
        modified_value = value
        original_rgb_set(self, instance, modified_value)

RGB.__set__ = custom_rgb_set
workbook = load_workbook(file)
```

you can debug in the value variable in the function custom_rgb_set, my faulty values where "0" so I skipped those as they were not necessary. But, see if you can find what the faulty values are and make a new RGB.**set** with the faulty ones removed or converted to the right format like 'FFFFFF'.