# Read an excel file obtained by requests.POST( Python )

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, post

I use the POST method via the requests library to download an EXCEL file.

```
payload = json.dumps({
  "data_ids": [
    "124902201",
    "124835548"
  ]
})

headers = {
  'Accept': 'application/vnd.ms-excel', 
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  }


response=requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=payload)

file_excel=pandas.read_excel(response.content)
```

When I tried the query on Postman, it returns me a response in Bytes form. So the idea I had was to read this file and convert it to Excel format and then load it into a dataframe.
Is it possible.

Answer (score 1):

Install `openpyxl`

```
pip install openpyxl
```

Pandas can read the `response.content` directly

```
import pandas as pd
import io

file_extension = "xlsx"

(...)

if file_extension == 'xlsx':
    excel_data = pd.read_excel(resp.content, engine='openpyxl')
elif file_extension == 'xls':
    excel_data = pd.read_excel(resp.content)
```

EDIT: Ok, now I've tested that this does the trick.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But still the same problem.
**********************************************************************************
ValueError: Colors must be aRGB hex values

Comment: Then maybe it's an old excel file, with a possible solution here https://stackoverflow.com/a/66647319/7721925

Comment: From what I understand, the response retrieved by pyhon is in BYTES format, so the read_excel cannot locate an excel file.

Comment: I tested the code above with and without `io.BytesIO`, both worked. If I remember correctly, the `read_excel` recently added the feature of receiving binary direction.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, Geoffrey Garrett your suggestion worked for reading both versions of excel files from disk.  But I had to modify read_excel() for 'xls', by adding engine='xlrd' and I had to install current version of xlrd.  Using current version of Pandas also.  Hope this helps others.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32555922)